# SQL BCP Permission needed?

Tags: sql-server

Need to check a permission level, a user needs bulk insert\update\delete permission.
If I add them to "BulkAdmin" server role, will this be enough? (Running SQL 2012)

Answer (score 2):

The ["server role"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669065%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) bulkadmin only gives permissions for bulk inserts.

Insert, update, and delete permissions are per database (or "fixed-database" roles). So you need to grant these permissions on a per database level. I'm guessing what you want is to use db_datawriter fixed database role, which can "add, delete, or change data in all user tables". You might also want them to be a db_datareader ([see database-level roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121(v=sql.110).aspx)).